# PostgreSQL ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS"

Tags: postgresql

Por favor ayuda,

Al crear la tabla empleado me arroja el siguiente error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 5: emp_cod AS ('EMP' + RIGHT ('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, posic_i...
                ^
```

SQL state: 42601
Character: 145

En SQL Server Funciona al 100%, mas no en PostgreSQL.

=======================Adjunto codigo============================

```
-- Crear Tabla Empleados

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_empleados
(
    emp_id smallint NOT NULL, -- Identificador no visible al usuario
    emp_cod AS ('EMP' + RIGHT ('0000' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, emp_id), (4))), -- Visible: EMP-0001
    emp_nom varchar(60) NOT NULL, --Nombre completo
    emp_sal numeric,
    emp_gen char (1) NOT NULL, -- Genero
    emp_stt bool DEFAULT 't',
    
    CONSTRAINT pk_emp_id PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_emp_nom UNIQUE (emp_nom),
    CONSTRAINT ck_emp_sal CHECK (emp_sal >0),
    CONSTRAINT ck_emp_gen CHECK (emp_gen IN ('M', 'F')) --CHECK Masculino / Femenino
);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

--- Gracias anticipadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente estamos ante un caso de **redundancia de datos**. Por un lado tienes la columna `emp_id` y por otro lado tendrías la columna `emp_cod` que generaría un valor basado en `emp_id` pero con un prefijo. Pones un comentario diciendo que `emp_id` queda *invisible al usuario*. No sé qué significa eso.

Si significa que no se muestre en las consultas, simplemente no lo pongas en el `SELECT`, generando un valor con prefijo basado en el valor de `emp_id`. Así, tus datos no vivirán duplicados en la tabla. Convendría también declarar a `emp_id` de un tipo *serial*, siguiendo tu código, lo declaramos como `smallserial`. [Revisa aquí](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-serial/) para ver los diferentes tamaños de los tipos de dato `serial`.

La tabla quedaría así:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_empleados (
    emp_id smallserial NOT NULL, -- Identificador no visible al usuario
    emp_nom varchar(60) NOT NULL, --Nombre completo
    emp_sal numeric,
    emp_gen char (1) NOT NULL, -- Genero
    emp_stt bool DEFAULT 't',
    
    CONSTRAINT pk_emp_id PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_emp_nom UNIQUE (emp_nom),
    CONSTRAINT ck_emp_sal CHECK (emp_sal >0),
    CONSTRAINT ck_emp_gen CHECK (emp_gen IN ('M', 'F')) --CHECK Masculino / Femenino
);

INSERT INTO tbl_empleados (emp_nom,emp_sal,emp_gen) VALUES 
  ('Nombre 1',800,'M'), 
  ('Nombre 2',900,'F'), 
  ('Nombre 3',500,'M');
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 3
> ```

```
-- Uso contextual
SELECT 
  to_char(emp_id, '"EMP0"FM0000') AS emp_cod,
  emp_id,
  emp_nom,
  emp_sal,
  emp_gen,
  emp_stt
FROM tbl_empleados;
```

| emp_cod | emp_id | emp_nom | emp_sal | emp_gen | emp_stt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMP00001 | 1 | Nombre 1 | 800 | M | t |
| EMP00002 | 2 | Nombre 2 | 900 | F | t |
| EMP00003 | 3 | Nombre 3 | 500 | M | t |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_empleados;
```

| emp_id | emp_nom | emp_sal | emp_gen | emp_stt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nombre 1 | 800 | M | t |
| 2 | Nombre 2 | 900 | F | t |
| 3 | Nombre 3 | 500 | M | t |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vasH0BgI)

Answer (score 3):

Es un error de sintaxis, PostgreSQL y SQL Server no usan el mismo "SQL". SQL Server usa T-SQL y PostgreSQL usa SQL + PL/pgSQL.

Creo que tendrías que usar

```
emp_cod varchar(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
('EMP' || LPAD(CAST(emp_id AS varchar), 4, '0')) STORED
```

`GENERATED ALWAYS` genera valores en la columna, mientras que `LPAD` agrega caracteres a la izquierda. Si quisieras generar un código que aumente de forma secuencial podrías usar `SERIAL`

[PostgreSQL LPAD](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-lpad/)

[PostgreSQL Identity Column](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-identity-column/)

[Using PostgreSQL SERIAL To Create Auto-increment Column](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-serial/)

Comment: Hola René, excelente tu repuesta y muy bien explicado, lo resolví a la 1ra. despues de mas de 15 días buscando...Que viva stackoverflow.

Comment: Una ayuda mas con este mismo codigo, no he podido poner un valor por default en el array de Genero: CONSTRAINT ck_emp_gen CHECK (emp_gen IN ('M','F')) DEFAULT 'M' -- CHECK Masculino / Femenino y 'M' por DEFAULT.

Answer (score 0):

aqui la solucion a mi problema, gracias al colaborador René.

[image: tbl_Empleados_Solucion]

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).